# Which DVD editions of “The Last Unicorn” are commendable?

Tags: movie, the-last-unicorn

There have been several editions of [*The Last Unicorn*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Unicorn_%28film%29) on DVD. [Peter S. Beagle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_S._Beagle), author of the screenplay (and of the [book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Unicorn) that the movie is based on), was in a dispute with the distributors of the movie for a long time. He [did not get any royalties from the US (zone 1) DVD](http://www.conlanpress.com/html/dvd.html), and furthermore that DVD was from a low-quality copy. In 2007, a [remastered copy](http://www.conlanpress.com/html/dvd.html) was released as a zone 1 DVD, still earning Beagle no royalties. Meanwhile, there was a [German DVD](http://www.amazon.de/Das-letzte-Einhorn-Arthur-Rankin/dp/B0002GTRGK) which as far as I know [did earn him royalties](http://groups.google.com/group/rec.arts.anime.misc/browse_thread/thread/fd0de4f769244885/d80563e27e255e65?lnk=gst&q=%22last+unicorn%22+dvd#d80563e27e255e65). However, [Conlan](http://www.conlanpress.com/html/dvd.html) states that “Except for the copies that were purchased through Conlan Press via this website, or at Peter's sales table at various conventions, none of the other Last Unicorn DVDs have ever paid him a cent.” Does that apply only to zone 1 editions, or also to the German DVD?

Apparently Beagle's legal dispute has ended; the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Unicorn_%28film%29#Legal_controversy_ended) unfortunately lacks references.

Which DVD editions of *The Last Unicorn* (and which sellers, if applicable) are commendable? That is, what should one purchase to get a high-quality DVD for which Beagle receives royalties?

Comment: What a great movie, and what a super-great song.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have managed to contact Mr. Beagle through some contacts, and here is what I asked:

> Some of my friends and I are very curious to know where we can
>   purchase a high quality DVD copy of The Last Unicorn for which you
>   will receive royalties?

Here is his answer in full:

> Hi Nathan,
>
> It sometimes takes me a while to sort through all the messages coming
>   in; my apologies. Thank you for your nice note, and for asking about
>   royalties on DVD purchases. I'm glad to say that last year I settled
>   matters with the parent company, ITV, that owns the film. Therefore,
>   all DVD and blu-ray sales will bring me royalties! If you'd like me to
>   autograph or personalize a copy of the movie, I do that through
>   www.conlanpress.com.
>
> Thank you again for your support - and please keep enjoying the story!
>
> Best wishes, Peter

Obviously I can't cite anything anywhere to prove it, but, I'm not making it up, and you're welcome. ;)

UPDATE:

After realizing I now have more clear search terms, with his words to use, I did some more searching and came up with [this](http://www.conlanpress.com/):

> HERE'S THE FIRST SPECTACULAR FRUIT OF THE SETTLEMENT — ANNOUNCING NEW
>   COLLECTOR'S EDITION LAST UNICORN ART PRINTS BY HIDEMI KUBO AND BRIANNE
>   DROUHARD  (ALSO 15% OFF UNTIL 10/31!)
>
> Peter S. Beagle and ITV have settled all differences over the animated
>   version of THE LAST UNICORN, and are now working together to bring
>   Peter's creation to the world in amazing new ways. To celebrate this
>   deal, Conlan Press is offering everyone 15% off on all LAST
>   UNICORN-related items, from now through Midnight on October 31st.
>
> This new deal makes many things possible that couldn't be done before.
>   We're delighted to be able to sell, for the first time, limited
>   edition museum-quality archival prints featuring development art from
>   the animated film and wonderful new pictures inspired by it.

Obviously this confirms what Mr. Beagle said to me in email. :D

(Also, had I bothered to go to where he directed me in his email I would have saved myself the search.)

Comment: Gotta love Word of God.

Comment: As an aside, I actually sought him out to ask because I love the movie a great deal and I also wanted to know how to make sure that he got the $$.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find anything definitive when I asked the question. Great to see that Peter S. Beagle is finally earning royalties for his work!